# Entity Framework Data Migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration, entity-framework-migrations

We´ve changed some logic in our application and now we add some fields within a migration but the existing entries should get some values also. Therefor we need to load the entry, calculate some values and need to add this value to the new field. So how to access the data which is requested with the `Sql-Method`? The defaultValue-Flag of the AddColumn-Method will not work because every entry has a value calculated different.

Here somekind of workflow:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<uint>(
            name: "Field",
            table: "Table",
            type: "INTEGER",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0u);


        var builder = migrationBuilder.Sql("SELECT * FROM Table");

        var data = builder.AccessData; // here I´m unsure how to access the data

        data.Field = Calculator(data);

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(data); // this one is also not cleare
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MigrationBuilder` is a way to express in a fluent, C#-friendly fashion the SQL code that will be executed during the migration itself. Even if the code you write and the "intermediate files" generated by the migration tool look as C#, at the end the migration becomes pure SQL that neither knows nor can communicate with your application.

Therefore, if you need to process existing data, all your logic must happen DB-side and must be expressed as operations on the `MigrationBuilder`. Of course in the `Up` and `Down` methods of the migration you can leverage all the power of C# to build the raw SQL statements to be provided to the `migrationBuilder.Sql(...)`. Also, consider that the whole migration is executed in a transaction and that a "volatile" stored procedure can turn out to be useful to extract a complex migration logic.

Comment: Thank you this is clear now. Is there a common way using EF Core to migrate data?

Comment: Since migration of data is something that can vary a lot from case to case, I cannot suggest you a one-size-fits-all solution. Of course some recurring scenarios have a "standard" way to address them; for example adding a column calculated from the existing values of many tables, converting a column type (from enum string to number or viceversa), splitting or merging tables, etc.